# Conditionally include javascript file in xbl

Tags: xforms, orbeon, xbl

Can I conditionally include javascript file and css files.

`<xbl:script src="/apps/xforms-sandbox/samples/myfile.js" />`

Can this be done conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, in Orbeon Forms, you can't conditionally include scripts with `<xbl:script>` or CSS with `<xbl:style>`. To include dynamic resources, use HTML the elements `<xhtml:script>` and `<xhtml:style>` you generate with XSTL, inside the `<xbl:template>` of your XBL component. If you can use static resource, you should:

1. To avoid duplication — If you have multiple instances of your component when the page is loaded, then the same JavaScript or CSS will end up being included multiple times in the page. You might say: well, but this is the case anyway when using `<xbl:script>` and `<xbl:style>`. Yes, but this is a [bug](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=312632&group_id=168&atid=350207), which hopefully we'll get a chance to fix soon.
2. To benefit from automatic minimization and combination — We are [planning](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=314490&group_id=168&atid=350207) to automatically combine and minimize the resources references in XBL components, just like we do for resources used by the core XForms engine itself. You will be able to benefit from this feature when it lands in the codebase if you use `<xbl:script>` and `<xbl:style>`.

Comment: Please look at this response. Syntaxhighlighter supports many languages and each requires its own js and css file. If xform user is trying to display XML it doesn't make sense to include other js and css files.

http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/xforms-output-as-xml-not-only-content-td3025610.html#a3041342

A cleaned up version is available at
https://github.com/binnyg/orbeon-xbl-samples

Comment: Understood: you have a valid case for dynamic resources. I updated my answer to mention that using HTML the elements `<xhtml:script>` and `<xhtml:style>` you generate with XSTL, inside the `<xbl:template>` of your XBL component is the way to go.